# Renormalizability of Inflationary Potential and the case of Einstein and Jordan Frame

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, cosmological-inflation

I am not an expert on Quantum Field Theory so I am not sure whether these are valid questions or not! My first question is

1. Since, inflation is a classical field theory phenomenon (Gravity plus a classical scalar field). We don't quantise anything till we calculate the fluctuations. Do we need to check whether the inflationary potentials are renormalizable?
2. Say, we know a potential is renormalizable in Jordan frame, is the renormalability guaranteed in Einstein frame. I am particularly concerned, as a simple power-law potential in Jordan frame can turn into some thing complicated by a conformal transformation in Einstein Frame.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this field either, but my understanding is that, since inflation is an effective field theory, renormalizability is not guaranteed and need not be checked (the tensor perturbations will be nonrenormalizable, since canonically quantized GR isn't). As for the second part of your question, since switching between the Einstein and Jordan frames is just a field redefinition, it shouldn't change the renormalizability of the theory.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the answer. I am looking for a detailed proof/calculation/direction.